# Called from Wrong Thread Exception in Robotium Testcase

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, robotium

I'm writing Testcase using `Robotium` for my android app which has multiple activities. The app implements `Drawer` in UI. But when solo opens drawer, it gives the exception `Called From Wrong Thread Exception`. Drawer loads when ActionBar Home is clicked.

```
public void test4Drawer()
{
    solo1.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
    Boolean actual=solo1.searchText("About");
    Boolean expected =true;
    assertEquals("Drawer Not Loaded",expected,actual);
}
```

Comment: a not related thing with your issue. Use primitive type when you can. In your case it is preferable to use boolean instead of Boolean

Answer (score 1):

In you setUp():

```
mActivity = getActivity();
```

And in you test case add this:

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        solo1.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
    }
});
```

But the error should not appear when you use standart robotium methods. If this solution does not work for you, please share full stack trace here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the 4.3 version of Robotium `runOnUiThread` will not help.

As the associated [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/detail?id=553) says it's fixed in Robotium 4.3.1 version.

Download it [here](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/list).

If you keep the `runOnUiThread` code and upgrade the lib, you will have a much more explicit exception in the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32201): java.lang.RuntimeException:
  This method can not be called from the main application thread
```

Remove the `runOnUiThread` and it will be fine.