# Android Robotium Testing, Runtime Exception This method can not be called from the main application thread

Tags: java, android, robotium

So I am testing my android app using Robotium and when I go to click on the item in my list it by `solo.clickInList(0,1);` using gives me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: This method can not be called from the main application thread
at android.app.Instrumentation.validateNotAppThread(Instrumentation.java:1787)
at android.app.Instrumentation.runOnMainSync(Instrumentation.java:348)
at com.robotium.solo.Scroller.scrollListToLine(Scroller.java:326)
at com.robotium.solo.Scroller.scrollList(Scroller.java:276)
at com.robotium.solo.Scroller.scroll(Scroller.java:195)
at com.robotium.solo.Scroller.scroll(Scroller.java:156)
at com.robotium.solo.Scroller.scrollDown(Scroller.java:169)
at com.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForView(Waiter.java:154)
at com.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:521)
at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickInList(Clicker.java:516)
at com.robotium.solo.Solo.clickInList(Solo.java:1244)
at com.teamname.tutortrader.AvailableSessionsActivityTest.testViewOneSession(AvailableSessionsActivityTest.java:119)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.access$000(InstrumentationTestCase.java:36)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase$2.run(InstrumentationTestCase.java:189)
at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1855)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I am using the `@UiThreadTest` on top of my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found here it looks like a bug in robotium. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200643/6150020. You can probably do the same thing by yourself without robotium.

`public void onListViewItemClick(){
          Activity activity = getActivity();
          final ListView listView = (ListView)activity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
          getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.performItemClick(listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, listView.getItemIdAtPosition(0));
            }
        });
}`

Comment: I'm using robotium 5.2.1, it this still a problem?

Comment: The problem should be fixed  though. Probably annotation @UiThreadTest makes the mess. As it is written in the doc -  note that instrumentation methods may not be used when this annotation is present. Have you tried to remove it? If you has other methods that should run on main thread, you can use runOnMainSync.

Comment: When I remove the `@UiThreadTest` it gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. I'll see how runOnMainSync works.

Comment: Okay this was my bad, nothing to do with robotium. you are right that it was the @UiThreadtest. I was doing some random adapter stuff that was messing with it. Thanks for your help